# R - Date and time axis out of order?

Tags: r, date, time, graph

Hi basically I have data for a 3 month period and when I go to graph it the points graph out of order.

```
plot(BG.data$TIMESTAMP, BG.data$Diff_H1H2, main="Difference between High 1 & High 2 vs Date & Time" , xlab = "Date & Time", ylab = "Difference (°C)", ylim=c(-4.5,7))
```

and then the x axis seems to be random. The points go 01/05/2014 0:00, 10/06/2014 6:15, 19/04/2014 4:00,  29/04/2014 3:00. Where's the pattern and how to make it so that it orders it from the first day in May to the last day in July?

Comment: Without your data we can only guess. Most likely you need to transform your datetimes into a POSIXct object. See `help("strptime")` for details.

Answer (score 0):

The display as `01/05/2014 0:00` means you don't really have datetime values, and most probably have factor values which would be expected to get scrambled when converted to numeric values. Factors sometimes  need to be coerced to character but I think that as.POSIXct.default will detect that.  Try this:

```
BG.data$TIMESTAMPb <- strptime( BG.data$TIMESTAMP, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
BG.data$Diff_H1H2b  <- strptime(  BG.data$Diff_H1H2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

OR:

```
BG.data$TIMESTAMPb <- as.POSIXct( BG.data$TIMESTAMP, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
BG.data$Diff_H1H2b  <- as.POSIXct(  BG.data$Diff_H1H2, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Then redo your plot with the new variables. (There are sometimes timezone issues that will arise.)